# Why regenerated Postgres table raise error in Vapor?

Tags: postgresql, vapor

A table in production environment was created like this:

```
-- DDL generated by Postico 1.5.10
-- Not all database features are supported. Do not use for backup.

-- Table Definition ----------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE "TempUser" (
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    "Uuid" text NOT NULL,
    "dateCreated" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    "lastRequestDate" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    "lastRequestLocation" text,
    "numOfRequest" bigint NOT NULL,
    comment text NOT NULL,
    "lastRequestDescription" text NOT NULL,
    "bookedSeats" text NOT NULL,
    "bookUntil" timestamp without time zone,
    "lastEventVisited" text
);

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "pk:TempUser.id" ON "TempUser"(id int8_ops);
```

Why I remove table in `dev` environment and create like this in Postgres console, I got following error after try writing programmatically:

```
[ ERROR ] PostgreSQLError.server.error.ExecConstraints: POST /registerTempUser null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint (ErrorMiddleware.swift:26)
[ DEBUG ] Possible causes for PostgreSQLError.server.error.ExecConstraints: Failing row contains (null, 015574220836500, 2020-07-09 19:42:36.803846, 2020-07-09 19:42:36.803846, null, 1, , POST /registerTempUser HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Typ..., [], null, null). (ErrorMiddleware.swift:26)
```

Why, what is wrong?

Tried set sequence thing:

```
 select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"TempUser"', 'id'), 1);
 select currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"TempUser"', 'id'));
```

nothing changed.

Comment: It looks like id @Field in your Fluent model should be marked as automatic to support autoincrement

Comment: I checked here, but found nothing like `automatic` attribute https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/fluent/overview/ Would u explain more?

Comment: try to change your id type to `@ID("id", generatedBy: . database)` [reference](https://github.com/vapor/fluent-kit/blob/master/Sources/FluentKit/Properties/ID.swift)